# How to view Layer information in our web mapping application?

Tags: web-applications, mapping, gis, openlayers, geoserver

I have successfully published layers within Geoserver. When I click on any part of map after layer-preview, it displays the relevant layer information from the shapefile in the Geoserver. However, I'm encountering an issue where the published layer information is not being displayed in my web application. I am seeking guidance on how to address this issue and enable the display of layer information within my web application.

Comment: How do you obtain the information?  For example as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html ?

Comment: Did you set up the CORS ?